# Public DNS has changed and now my wordpress site is broken

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I set up an AWS EC2 micro instance with LAMP and installed Wordpress and a theme and activated the child theme. I have made numerous changes to the site and all was good.

I then resized the instance. I did not have an elastic IP set up. I now have a new public IP.

I can access the instance via SSH and everything works. But, I cannot load the site via its new public IP. It just keeps loading and timing out.

My security groups are fine, all are open.

I have tried following the article on changing the url but none of those suggestions work (https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

I believe that I need to search and replace my old url with the new one. But I can't find the old url and the command `[ec2-user ~]$ curl localhost | grep wp-content` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing wp general settings`General Settings Console` and update site URL with `Elastic IP i-e http://xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa`.
This will work.

Comment: Can I ssh into the General Settings Console? I thought that could only be accessed once logged into the site?